# What kind of logic should be in Rails before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, controller

Should I load and check the presence of the DB source in before filter?

In our application, we always load and check presence of DB source which has an id passed in by params. I'm not sure if this is a good pattern.

like:

```
before_action :set_org

private

def seg_org
  @org ||= Organization.find params[:id]
  resource_not_found unless @org
end
```

Comment: Doesn't [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) already raise an error? In which case your `resource_not_found` won't get executed at all. So it's better to just remove it.

Comment: This is actually how the [rails scaffold generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb) sets up the controller by default (lines 7 & 55). So that's a pretty decent sign that if nothing else it's not a horrible idea or way of doing things

Comment: @vee `find` won't raise any error. If nothing found, it will return `nil`.

Comment: If you want to grow as developer, good answer is: *none* :)

Comment: hmmm…… what do you mean? @PavelMikhailyuk

Comment: Avoid `state` as long as possible. https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+before+filters+are+wrong&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: @hiveer what version of Rails? In Rails 5, `find` definitely raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if record doesn't exist

Comment: @m.simonborg We didn't use ActiveRecord. We use SQLServer and write procs to get data. So the return of `find` depends on the return of proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, finding a record and setting it as an instance variable is a common convention for controller filters. Generally though, any piece of code that gets run for multiple actions is a good candidate. Say you want to redirect to the log in page if the current user is not logged in.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  private

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know who did it.  : )
Any way, I vote you back.

Comment: @hiveer lol thanks : ) It's just nice to get a comment when something's down voted so it can be improved. I feel like this is a reasonable answer so I was just confused. was this answer helpful at all?

Comment: Yes, it's helpful. Especially your explanation on it. But you know the authentication case is a very common used case. If you can give some other examples from official use case or the official  explanation documents, that would be great.

Comment: @hiveer ok, I replaced the example with one from the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters